# How do I make my functions specific to individual objects in an array, rather than globally effecting them all?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My functions showMore and showLess are being called for all objects in the array when the onClick is fired. I need these functions to be called for each object individually. both of these functions toggle between showing more or less text information for a particular client. At the moment, if you click on one show more, more text is showed for all clients. I hope this makes sense

```
import React from "react";
import rob from "../../assets/rob.jpeg";
import sydney from "../../assets/sydney.jpeg";

import blockchain from "../../assets/blockchain.jpg";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./clients.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: rob,
    title: "Robert C Robertson",
    subtitle: "Unboxed Digital",
    keypoints: (
      <li>
        <ul>Built multiple websites using Oxygen builder</ul>
      </li>
    ),
    body: "I was reasearching how to get in to the web development industry, and found the Auckland Wordpress Meetup group. I reached out to the group and Rob got back to me, he was running the group at the time. Rob told me that he had started his own web development business and was looking for an intern, I jumped at the oppurtunity! I completed my internship with Rob and continued with him for a while doing paid work on sites such as and",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image: sydney,
    title: "Phone",
    github: "https://github.com",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    image: blockchain,
    title: "Blockchain",
    github: "https://github.com",
  },
];

const Clients = () => {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
  const showMoreClick = () => {
    setShowMore(true);
  };
  const showLessClick = () => {
    setShowMore(false);
  };

  return (
    <section id="clients">
      <h5>Who I've worked for</h5>
      <h2>Clients</h2>
      <div className="container clients__container">
        {data.map(({ id, image, title, body, subtitle, keypoints }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <article key={id} className="clients__item">
                <div className="clients__item-image">
                  <img src={image} alt={title} />
                </div>
                <div className="clients__info">
                  <h3>{title}</h3>
                  <h4>{subtitle}</h4>
                  <h5>{keypoints}</h5>
                </div>

                <div>
                  {!showMore && (
                    <small
                      className="clients__showmoreless"
                      onClick={showMoreClick}
                    >
                      See more
                    </small>
                  )}
                  {showMore && (
                    <div>
                      <small onClick={showLessClick}>See less</small>
                      <p>{body}</p>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              </article>
              <div></div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Clients;
```

Answer (score 1):

The showMore if condition is not capable to distinguish which data-row open because the state hook can save only true/false (as a boolean).

You can save which row is open by storing the `id`.

```
const Clients = () => {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState();
  const showMoreClick = (id) => {
    setShowMore(id);
  };
  const showLessClick = () => {
    setShowMore(undefined);
  };

  return (
    <section id="clients">
      <h5>Who I've worked for</h5>
      <h2>Clients</h2>
      <div className="container clients__container">
        {data.map(({ id, image, title, body, subtitle, keypoints }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <article key={id} className="clients__item">
                <div className="clients__item-image">
                  <img src={image} alt={title} />
                </div>
                <div className="clients__info">
                  <h3>{title}</h3>
                  <h4>{subtitle}</h4>
                  <h5>{keypoints}</h5>
                </div>

                <div>
                  {showMore !== id  && (
                    <small
                      className="clients__showmoreless"
                      onClick={() => showMoreClick(id)}
                    >
                      See more
                    </small>
                  )}
                  {showMore === id && (
                    <div>
                      <small onClick={showLessClick}>See less</small>
                      <p>{body}</p>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              </article>
              <div></div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```